# Multiple inputs with react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Is it possible to have multiple input fields using react hook form?

My scenario is that I require an abbreviation of two characters from the user and it doesn't look great having a full input box and just limiting the number of characters allowed so I thoughts instead to have two very small inputs for one character each; it seems a bit more intuitive to me.

The problem is that if I add multiple Input's into a Form Control it renders them separately rather than together; I'm also unsure how to manage default values and values etc.

My code is below:

```
const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof CreateProject>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(CreateProject),
    defaultValues: {
      abbreviation: projectById?.abbreviation.substring(0, 2) || "",
    },
  });
<FormField
            control={form.control}
            disabled={type === "edit" && formDisabled}
            name="abbreviation"
            render={({ field }) => {
              return (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Icon</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <div className="relative flex">
                   
                      <Input
                        className="rounded-l-none border-l-0"
                        maxLength={2}
                        placeholder="AA"
                        {...field}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              );
            }}
          />
```

Comment: why not just have seperate form fields, and then style using css?